# Facebook API, make a draft or privacy "self"

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i use Facebook API to publish on my Facebook page. My code works, but now i need to publish my post or like draft or with privacy "self", but it's still publishing post visible to everyone. Here's my code:

```
public function makeOggistiPost($queryRow)

{
    $pageId = PAGE_ID;
    $pageToken = $this->dbService->getPageToken($pageId);
    if (!empty($pageToken)) {
        $postMessage = [
            $this->clearString($queryRow->titolo_ita),
            $this->clearString($queryRow->abstr_ita),
            "Continua su https://www.progettohmr.it/OggiSTI/?id=" . $queryRow->id_evento
        ];
        try {
            $response = $this->facebook->post("/" . $pageId . "/photos", [
                "message" => implode(" ", $postMessage),
                "url" => HMR_URL . $queryRow->immagine,
                "privacy"=>  '{value: "SELF"}',
                "published" => "true"
            ], $pageToken);
```

Someone could tell me how to make my post like a draft or with privacy "self"? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Those privacy settings are for user profiles. Try setting `is_published` to `false` instead.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/post